# Can iOS Apps edit my files and save changes to my App?

Tags: ios

I want to allow other apps associated with .docx files to be able to edit the files I have inside my App document library. Is that applicable?

Comment: No it's not, all your app documents are private and can't be opened from other applications. You are trying to do what iOS tries so much to prevent. ;)

Comment: ios is a very guarded environment. Even somehow you figured out a loop hole, the guardings of the gates will never let your app see the light of day. Maybe you can do that on andriod or windows phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible! Each app has its own private folder that is not accessible by other applications! If this was allowed then any app could break other apps files. Doesn't seem logical